# Can any Laurent polynomial symmetric under q->1/q and whose roots are all roots of unity be written as a ratio of products of quantum numbers?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra

Quantum dimensions are quantum integer fractions (or so I heard). 
Example: $G_2(\lambda_2)$ (technically it should read q^{1/6}, I know...)

$q^{-10}+q^{-8}+q^{-2}+1+q^2+q^8+q^{10}$ = $q_{12}*q_7*q_2/q_6/q_4$

where $q_n$ is shorthand for $(q^n-q^{-n})/(q-1/q)$.

Obviously the left hand side must be symmetric under q->1/q and all roots
are roots of unity. Are these conditions already sufficient that a given
Laurent polynome can be converted into a quantum integer fraction? Is there
even a constructive algorithm? (BTW, I believe the result should be unique
since each quantum integer $q_n$ introduces a new root of unity.)
In the example the roots are $(-1)^{m/7}$ and $(-1)^{m/12}$ so I might
begin with $l.h.s./q_{12}/q_7$, compute the roots of that etc., and this
algorithm *might* already work.

Comment: If coeffieicnets are in Z, then yes. Then q^N*Laurent poly divides q^M-1 so is a product of cyclotomic polynomials, hence can be written in the given form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any polynomial with integer coefficients whose roots all are roots of unity are products of [cyclotomic polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). Cyclotomic polynomials are in turn ratios of quantum integers.

For quantum groups you should be able to use a quantum analogue of the [Weyl dimension formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Weyl_dimension_formula) to get explicit formulas.